# Dirac Delta function identities

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm using the definition of the one dimensional dirac-delta function, $\delta(x)$, being, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx = f(0) \tag1$$ and I'm doing a question which asks me to (via ordinary integral manipulations) show that, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x).\tag2$$
The solution said to use substitution of $u=|a|x$ and $du=|a|dx$ to get $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(ax)f(x)dx = \frac{1}{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\pm u)f\biggl(\frac{u}{|a|}\biggl) du= \frac{1}{|a|}f(0) \tag3.$$ And then by equating the LHS of $(3)$ with with the LHS of $(1)$ we get the identity in $(2)$. That makes sense. Only thing is I don't get why one would have used the substitution, $u=|a|x$, as opposed to the seemingly more natural, $u=ax.$ Can anybody tell me why they did that in the solution? The short answer is because that is what gets the correct answer. But the identity in $(2)$ seems to be a major/common one of the Dirac Delta function, which seems to imply that, $$\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{a}\delta(x),$$ doesn't hold for negative $a$. If that is the case can someone explain why?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: What is $\delta(-x)$? Equivalently, what are the even and odd parts of $\delta(x)$?

Comment: Hint: Trace what happens to the integration limits when $a<0$.

Comment: @Qmechanic Ahh that makes sense, I got it thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fisrt, let us come back to the initial step:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\,\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}adx\,\delta(ax)
$$

For $a$ positive we can make $du=adx$ and the limit of the integration are the same. For $a$ negative, the limits of the integration are interchanged when we perform the integration in $u$. If we interchange back the limits of integration this will cost an extra $(-1)$ factor, since:

$$
\int_{a}^{b}du=-\int_{b}^{a} du
$$

Then we have that if $a$ is negative, we have $\delta(ax)=(-1)\frac{1}{a}\delta(x)$. At the end we can write for all signs of $a$: $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**<sup>1</sup> :

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{\boldsymbol{-}\infty}^{\boldsymbol{+}\infty}\!\delta\left(\alpha x+\beta\right)\mathrm{h}\left(x\right)\mathrm dx  =\int\limits_{\boldsymbol{-} \mathrm{sign}(\alpha) \, \infty}^{\boldsymbol{+}\mathrm{sign}(\alpha) \, \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\delta\left(u\right)\mathrm{h}\left(\dfrac{u-\beta}{\alpha}\right)\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\alpha}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}

---

<sup>$^{1}$
[Physical meaning of the Jacobian in relation to Dirac delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371700/physical-meaning-of-the-jacobian-in-relation-to-dirac-delta-function/371706#371706), $\:\color{blue}{\textbf{Example A :}}$.</sup>

Comment: Very kind user can you see my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753486/electric-field-flux-proportional-to-the-field-lines-generated-by-for-example-a