# Electric field flux proportional to the field lines generated by (for example) a static charge

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, vector-fields, electromagnetism

Suppose we have a stationary positive charge at a point in space that we call $+Q$. We know by definition that the flow of the electrostatic field is given by, in its simplified form,

$$\Phi_S(\vec E)=\vec E \cdot \vec S=ES\cos \alpha=+k_e\frac{Q}{r^2}S\cos \alpha$$

where $S$ is the Gaussian surface and $\alpha$ is the angle formed between the electric field lines and the surface vector $\vec S=S\hat{\bf n}$. Suppose that $N$ are the lines of force of the electrostatic field coming out of the charge $+Q$. How do I prove that

$$\Phi_S(\vec E)=+k_e\frac{Q}{r^2}S\cos \alpha\color{red}{=KN}\iff \Phi_S(\vec E) \propto N$$
where $K$ is a constant of proportionality?

Comment: The notion of "number" of field lines being equal to flux is an intuitive visualization. You may as well ask what is the number of points that constitute an interval. [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/775024/304394).

Comment: @KurtG. In what sense I may as well ask what is the number of points that constitute an interval?

Comment: Flux is the integral of the scalar $\vec{E}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ over a surface. Replace scalar by a function on an interval and integrate. Nowhere do we need the notion of "number" of lines of $\vec{E}$, nor the notion of how many points $x$ constitute your interval.

Comment: @KurtG. Could you please give me an example by giving me an answer? But then is the notion of flow with lines of force a postulate? Thk.

Comment: I said 15 hours ago it is an intuitive visualization. Did you read that?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, of course.

Comment: In the related PSE link they elaborate more. I also believe your question is better suited on that other forum.

Comment: @KurtG. I will get my question as a duplicate.